# xdebug isn't breaking in certain files, everywhere else it's fine

Tags: laravel, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using Xdebug 2.2.5 on PHP 5.5.12 in the Laravel 4.2 Homestead Vagrant box and PHPStorm8 EAP 138.1751.

On most files, I can set a breakpoint and it works.

Controller\Manage\DashboardController extends Controller\Manage\BaseManageController extends Controller\BaseController extends \Controller.

It won't break on anything inside DashboardController and I can't figure out why.

I'm trying to break inside the method index(), but it won't.  If I move index() to BaseController, then it will break in it.  Also, if I break on the method that calls the action in my controller, and manually step into it, it just jumps past it (could have sworn that worked at least once before, but isn't now).

Any idea what could cause it?

This is my xdebug config:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000

xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.auto_trace = 1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
xdebug.var_display_max_children=512
xdebug.var_display_max_data=1024
```

Comment: 1) Does programmatic breakpoint works (by placing `xdebug_break();` into your code in that place)? 2) Collect xdebug logs and look into it -- maybe IDE sets breakpoint in wrong file (wrong path) etc --- you have to remember that xdebug works with final/resolved paths ONLY while IDE works with files as is (symlinks etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a capitalization issue on the folder names...

I had DashboardController in:
./controller/manage/DashboardController

The namespace in the PSR4 loader defines the controller directory, so that's fine.

The "manage" directory was the problem, it needed to be "Manage"

Somewhat odd as it still loaded and ran the file, but xdebug must be more picky somehow on where it will find the files so it wouldn't on anything in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably not getting executed, therefore the breakpoint doesn't get reached.

Comment: The break point is in the controller for a page view, and the page view does load, so it's totally getting executed.